# javascript if statement in for loop not finding ==

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, for-loop

I have a for loop and my traces to the console are showing that my variables are correct. epid is determined in another method.

```
 for (var i=0; i< $('#slideshow > div').length; i++) {
   var divid = $('#slideshow > div').eq(i);
   console.log(divid)
   console.log(epid)
   if ( divid == epid ) {
    alert("equal " + epid);
   } else {
    console.log("blah");
   };
};
```

At one point in the loop, the console shows that the element is the same, but the alert doesn't pop up.
CONSOLE:

```
<div style=​"height:​ 100%;​ display:​ none;​ " id=​"ep5">​…​</div>​
<div style=​"height:​ 100%;​ display:​ none;​ " id=​"ep6">​…​</div>​
blah
<div style=​"height:​ 100%;​ display:​ none;​ " id=​"ep6">​…​</div>​
<div style=​"height:​ 100%;​ display:​ none;​ " id=​"ep6">​…​</div>​
blah
<div style=​"height:​ 100%;​ display:​ none;​ " id=​"ep7">​…​</div>​
<div style=​"height:​ 100%;​ display:​ none;​ " id=​"ep6">​…​</div>​
blah
```

Comment: Really you should never write a loop like that. At the very least, save the value of `$('#slideshow > div')` in a variable. The way your code is written, the DOM lookup will be done **twice** on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: What are you trying to look for in your `for` loop?  Are you looking for a particular DOM object?  Are you looking to match the contents of a DOM object?  What exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`divid` is a jQuery object.  It will NEVER match another variable unless that variable points at exactly the same jQuery object.  `==` or `===` compares object references to see if they are exactly the same object.  It does not compare the contents of those objects.

If epid is a DOM object and the point of your code is to to compare DOM objects, then you should use `.get(i)` or `[i]` instead of `.eq(i)` for both `epid` and `divid`:

```
var divid = $('#slideshow > div').get(i);
```

---

Assuming `epid` is a DOM object and you're looking for which item in your slideshow matches that object, you can have much more efficient and correct code like this:

```
var items = $('#slideshow > div');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var divid = items[i];
    if ( divid === epid ) {
        alert("equal " + epid);
    } else {
        console.log("blah");
    }
}
```

---

If, you just want to know what index `epid` is in the slideshow collection, you don't need a `for` loop to manually find it - you can do that like this:

```
var index = $('#slideshow > div').index(epid);
```

Comment: Thanks...I had to also do epid.get(0); so that I was dealing with elements and not the $objects as you pointed out.  This was a huge lesson for me, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your code you want to compare the Html of the elements?

```
 for (var i=0; i< $('#slideshow > div').length; i++) {
   var divid = $('#slideshow > div').eq(i);
   console.log(divid)
   console.log(epid)
   if ( divid.html() == epid.html()) {
    alert("equal " + epid);
   } else {
    console.log("blah");
   };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two objects here .. It will only be true if is exactly the same object.. SO instead of == use ===  . Also lets assume that if each div has an id you can compare the id attribute of it..

```
for (var i=0; i< $('#slideshow > div').length; i++) {
   var divid = $('#slideshow > div').eq(i);
   var dID = divid.attr('id');
   var eID = epid.attr('id');
   console.log(divid);
   console.log(epid);
   if(dID != ''  && eID != ''){
       if ( dID == eID ) {
          alert("equal " + epid);
       } else {
         console.log("blah");
       };
    }
};
```

This will only work if the div already has a ID for it.. Or a class that is specific for each div..